# wordpress nextgen gallery stray </p>

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

Hello i am updating a WordPress site that was riddled with errors (over 1000...-'-) now i have gotten it down to 15 or so however one page has 105 errors and they are all caused by a stray p tag that is being generated after every image here's what the code is being outputted as

```
<div id="ngg-image-40" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box"  >
     <div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >
          <a href="a link" title="the title" class="shutterset_set_5" ><br />
               <img title="01596-01_1" alt="01596-01_1" src="the src" width="100" height="75" /><br />
         </a>
     </div>
</p></div>
```

As you can see there is a p tag there for no reason, I've tried Google but got no one with a solution to this problem, I've tried looking through all the php files for the nextgen gallery and couldn't figure it out the actual code that outputs the gallery is below.

```
<div id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box" <?php echo $image->style ?> >
<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail" >
    <a href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
        <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
        <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
        <?php } ?>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Again as you can see there is no reference to the p tag in the above. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I also did not find a solution within the gallery but I have to admit that I didn't search that well. I was lazy and fixed it with javascript as I use a custom javascript for my gallery. Maybe that helps you, too. It's MooTools btw. and assumes that the gallery div has the id "gallery":

```
var p = document.id('gallery').getPrevious();
if (p.get('tag') == 'p') {
    p.dispose();
}
```